# Exchange 2010 / Outlook 2016 integration with PHP

Tags: php, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a web app built on PHP and would like to add some integration with Exchange for the purpose of workflow automation. Specifically, I'd like PHP to be able to access appointment data for a number of given calendars. And vice versa, I'd like to be able to create appointments from the PHP system without requiring user interaction. What would be the best (simplest) way to integrate the two systems?

I have done a considerable amount of searching on the subject but can't find a clear indication of which approach is best and where to begin looking for the knowledge I'll need to implement it. I have skills in web dev but not in desktop apps or things like VB or powershell. Not afraid to learn but please take that into account with your answers :)

Thanks very much,
Tangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to archive that would be to use the ["Microsoft Exchange Webservices" (EWS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Here is a god generall starting point:

- [Start using web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900168(v=exchg.150).aspx)

And here are some links specified to your "how to handle the calendar" part from your question:

- [How to: Create appointments and meetings by using EWS in Exchange
  2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495611(v=exchg.150).aspx)
- [Creating appointments and meetings by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633661(v=exchg.80).aspx)
- [How to: Create all-day events by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn756538(v=exchg.150).aspx)
- [How to: Get appointments and meetings by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx)